# on solaris-sparc platform adding openMp support to an existing C project

Tags: c, openmp

I need some advise and help for re-compiling of an existing C project (which is a huge project) on a solaris8-sparc platform with "OpenMP". The point is i m not familiar neither with compiling nor parallel programing issues.
With a little google search i see that sun-studio 11 and 12 has openMP infrastructure already.
so how can i start compiling c files with openMP.

on the other hand

Can this be done by downloading a gcc compiler with an openMP support ( in a bundle)
and renaming and linking it with the previous cc's location
and including openmp headers to project files..
this is what i suppose but sure its not that simple. so what should i do ?
can you please kindly offer me a road map about it.

Answer (score 0):

Openmp support is compiler dependent. So you can't just take omp.h from gcc and use it with sun pro.

Use option   -xopenmp in sun pro (read more at http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/studio_openmp.html )

And you can take Full installation of recent gcc (4.2 and later) and use it for compiling all your programs with openmp pragmas.